# VC++ win32 API programming: how can I get the image out of the clipboard and display it in a windows?

Tags: c++, winapi, clipboard, visual-c++

Use SelectObject() on your memory DC to select the bitmap into it. This makes me puzzled.
I read the msdn but still don't know how to fill the second parameter of SelectObject().

Comment: If you have further questions about this, please create a *new* question instead of updating this one. For example: "I am trying to select a bitmap into a memory DC using SelectObject(). I don't understand the purpose of the second parameter to SelectObject(), even after reading MSDN. What should I pass to SelectObject()?"

Answer (score 8):

Call [`OpenClipbard()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649048%28VS.85%29.aspx) to open the clipboard and call [`GetClipboardData()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649039%28VS.85%29.aspx) with a type of `CF_BITMAP` to get the handle to the image data stored on the clipboard.  If there's no image on the clipboard, the NULL handle will be returned.

Then, inside your window's `WM_PAINT` handler, use [`BeginPaint()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183362%28VS.85%29.aspx) to get a device context for drawing into your window, and use [`CreateCompatibleDC()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa922550.aspx) to create a memory device context for the bitmap.  Use [`SelectObject()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa932923.aspx) on your memory DC to select the bitmap into it, and finally use [`BitBlt()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183370%28VS.85%29.aspx) to blit the bitmap from the memory DC onto the window's DC.  Don't forget to clean up -- call [`DeleteDC()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183533%28VS.85%29.aspx) to delete the memory DC, and call [`EndPaint()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162598%28VS.85%29.aspx) to end drawing.

Lastly, call [`CloseClipboard()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649035%28VS.85%29.aspx) when you're done.  Note that the clipboard owns the bitmap handle, and as soon as you call `CloseClipboard()`, the bitmap will be destroyed.  So, if you want to hang onto the bitmap after you've closed the clipboard, you'll need to make a copy of it.