# Yet another draw bitmap from clipboard thread

Tags: c++, winapi

I've got problem with blitting bitmap from windows clipboard. Bitmap gets here via Printscreen button.

Here's my code based on:[VC++ win32 API programming :how can i get the image out of the clipboard and display it in a winodws?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529342/vc-win32-api-programming-how-can-i-get-the-image-out-of-the-clipboard-and-dis/1529369#1529369)

```
bool SetBackgroundImage(HWND hwnd) {

    GetPrintScreen(hwnd));

    OpenClipboard(NULL);
    HBITMAP Image = (HBITMAP)GetClipboardData(CF_BITMAP);
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC wdc = BeginPaint(hwnd,&ps);
    HDC mdc = CreateCompatibleDC(wdc);
    SelectObject(mdc,Image);
    BitBlt(wdc,0,0,1000,700,mdc,10,10,SRCCOPY);
    DeleteDC(mdc);
    EndPaint(hwnd,&ps);
    CloseClipboard();

    return true;
}
```

(I've scrapped whole error handling etc)
I'm 99% sure there is an image in the clipboard (otherwise app would crash) also when i check it in (ex) paint, it's possible to paste it.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your window doesn't have any invalid region, so `BeginPaint` produces an HDC that's completely clipped.

`BeginPaint` should only be used in `WM_PAINT` handler. If you want to draw outside of `WM_PAINT` (which is generally not a good idea; only attempt it if you are sure you know what you are doing), use `GetDC` instead.

Comment: If i replace BeginPaint with GetDC and execute whole "drawing" code outside WM_PAINT it still doesn't work. I close clipboard after drawing operations are performed, but now im not sure if should i still keep that bitmap somewhere else or just dont care after i've painted it?

Comment: Generally, you want to store the bitmap handle and call `InvalidateRect`. That would trigger an eventual arrival of `WM_PAINT`, which is where you should be doing all your drawing. Realize that your window may be asked to repaint itself at any moment (e.g. another window covers then uncovers it), so you must have at hand all the information necessary to do so.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
case WM_PAINT:
    {
        hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

        OpenClipboard(NULL);
        HBITMAP Image = (HBITMAP)GetClipboardData(CF_BITMAP);
        if(Image)
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC mdc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
            SelectObject(mdc, Image);
            BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, 1000, 700, mdc, 10, 10, SRCCOPY);
            DeleteDC(mdc);
        }
        CloseClipboard();

        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    }
    break;
```

Worth noting in the documentation for `BeginPaint`:

> An application should not call BeginPaint except in response to a WM_PAINT message. Each call to BeginPaint must have a corresponding call to the EndPaint function.

So, you need to put the drawing code in your paint handler.  It's not clear if that's what you've done or not.  If you want to retrieve the bitmap from the clipboard in another place in the code you can, but you'll need to make a copy of it since as soon as you close the clipboard it will be destroyed.  That's not a problem here since I don't need it after the blit is done.

Comment: If i put my code in WM_PAINT indeed it works, but i aim (it's not a must) to start drawing somewhere else.